# [React-Native]How to render view outside status bar(both android and ios)?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wonder how to render components outside status bar(I don't want to cover components upon status bar). I tried to get the status bar height(StatusBar.currentHeight) but it returned undefined. I think this is a common question, how did you guys solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StatusBar.currentHeight` is working only for android, as suggested in the react-native documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html

If you want to get the StatusBar height on iOS, you can write your own react-native library, or use this one:

https://github.com/jgkim/react-native-status-bar-size

But you can also do something like that without third libraries:

```
const height = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight
```

Hope my answer can help you :)